# How to find the total length of strings in an array of strings

Tags: c

In the following array:

```
["fix", "cache", "four"];
```

Is there a way to get the total length of characters in the array? = 3 + 5 + 4 = `12`? Currently what I am doing is adding together all the lengths of the individual strings:

```
char * strings[] = {"fix", "cache", "four", NULL};
size_t len_strings = 0;
for (int i=0; strings[i] != NULL ;i++) 
    len_strings += strlen(strings[i]);

printf("StringLength: %lu\n", len_strings);
// StringLength: 12
```

Also, why couldn't the following be done instead?

```
for (int i=0; *strings != NULL ;i++) {
    len_strings += strlen(*strings++);
}
```

I can do the folllowing (but I believe it's the same as doing the array offset, just with a different notation)

```
for (int i=0; *(strings+i) != NULL ;i++) {
    len_strings += strlen(*(strings+i));
}
```

Comment: regarding; `printf("StringLength: %lu\n", len_strings);`  This will 'work' however, the correct format specifier for a `size_t` is `%zu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it the only way possible: iterating over the array and checking each string.

The pointer increment doesn't work because `strings` is not a pointer. It's an array, so you can't do `array++`. However you *can* do pointer arithmetic with it. You could also use a pointer to do what you initially wanted:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char * strings[] = {"fix", "cache", "four", NULL};
    char **pointer = strings;
    size_t len_strings = 0;
    for (int i=0; *pointer != NULL ;i++) {
        len_strings += strlen(*(pointer++));
    }

    printf("StringLength: %lu\n", len_strings);
}
```

It is not better, neither worse than indexing the array. It's just a way to do with `pointer++`. Notice that the parentheses around `(pointer++)` are not mandatory, but it's better to keep them. It can be confusing to rely on operator precedence when you have two operators with the same precedence and each is in one side of the operand.

Lastly, your belief is correct. For any array, this:

```
array[i]
```

is just the same as

```
*(array + i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through each string of the the strings array to get the total length of all the strings.

`strings` is an *array* of `char` pointers. You cannot use `++` operator with `strings` variable (`*strings++`) because it's not allowed to change the address of an array. If you want to use pointers, you can do

```
char **p_strs = strings;

for (int i=0; *p_strs != NULL ;i++) {
    len_strings += strlen(*p_strs++);
}
```

Yes, the `*(strings+i)` is same as `strings[i]`. From C Standard#6.5.2.1:

> The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))).

Comment: thanks for this -- I like that solution. Are you able to cast it in place instead of defining a new variable, i.e., `(char **) strings` or is that not allowed?

Comment: @TagC198 You can cast it but what you will do with it? Will you use `++` on that expression? Something like - `*((char **)strings)++`. No, that's not allowed. Go through the concept of _lvalue_. Standard says (#6.5.16) - _An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand_ and from #6.3.2.1 _A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type....._